# Given the path, how to extract only a part of it using python?

Tags: python, path

I have a path as '/img/dataset/A/B/3/5/img1.png'
How can I extract the '/A/B/3/5/img1.png' part out of this?

I tried
`path = '/img/dataset/A/B/3/5/img1.png'`

`extracted = path.partition('/')`

This gave me the whole path as the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
path[len('/img/dataset'):]
```

Strings share some properties with lists, indexing and `len` beeing some.

Comment: For more complicated path manipulations it's better to use PathLib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html